# Laravel query build not binding parameters correctly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

It seems that the query builder is binding the parameters in the wrong order.

Here is my query:

```
$query = DB::table('jobs');
$query->whereIn( 'status_id', $status_array);
$this_query->leftjoin( 'attribute_text_data', function($join) use ( $attribute_id, $attribute_value ){
        $join->on( 'jobs.job_id', '=', 'attribute_text_data.job_id' )
             ->where( 'attribute_id', '=', $attribute_id ) 
             ->where( 'attribute_value', '=', $attribute_value );
    });
```

And when I run this, I notice that the correct results aren't being returned. So I output the raw query and it appears that parameters have not been bound in the correct order:

```
select distinct `jobs`.`job_id` as `job_id`, `job_title`, `job_due_date`, `status_id`, `assigned_to_contact_id`,     `jobs`.`account_id`, `billing_account_id`, `attribute_text_data`.`attribute_value` as `attribute_value_text` 
from `jobs` left join `attribute_text_data` 
    on `jobs`.`job_id` = `attribute_text_data`.`job_id` 
    and `attribute_id` = ? 
    and `attribute_value` =    ? 
where `status_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?)
        [bindings] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
                [3] => 4
                [4] => 4 ( attribute_id )
                [5] => hourly (attribute_value )
            )
```

It seems that as status was added to the query first, it's parameters where added to the bindings array first. Then the attribute bindings were added. But it seems that the query is then rearranged and the parameters are not accessed in the correct order.

Is this a bug, or is there something wrong with my query syntax?

NB - It would be difficult to move the status part of the query to follow the attribute part, but could be done as a last resort. I feel that the bindings should be applied correctly instead of trying to get a work around.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? It works fine for me on the latest 4.2